# \titleformat is causing the section title to appear twice in Table of Contents

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, titlesec

Here is how it shows:

[image]

The section appears twice. Ideally I'd like it to be

1. BACKGROUND AND RATIONALE

with that dot and no bold.

Here is the `\titleformat` that is causing this behavior:

```
\titleformat{\section}%
[hang]% <shape>
{\clearpage\centering\bfseries\fontsize{14pt}{14}\selectfont}% <format>
{\thesection.\quad}% <label>
{0pt}% <sep>
{}% <before code>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double entry is caused by `\clearpage`. However, `\titlesec` has no effect on the the table of contents typesetting, so you should be more explicit about your setup.

For the moment here's how you can get an automatic `\clearpage` at `\section` without affecting the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]% <shape>
  {\centering\bfseries\fontsize{14pt}{14}\selectfont}% <format>
  {\thesection.\quad}% <label>
  {0pt}% <sep>
  {}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\section{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Background and rationale}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @egread Thanks for that quick answer. I just realised the clearpage issue just before you posted. So i just used `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}` which seem to do the trick. But I still can't get the dot between section and its number. Also do you know how to get the title of table of contents to center. This didn't work `\renewcommand\contentsname{\centering TABLE OF CONTENTS}}`

Comment: @Madhu It's impossible to say without knowing more details about your document; the class, for instance.

Comment: I am using extarticle class for my document. I am not doing any other formatting for titles except titleformat.